# What is the action on the higher cohomology groups of an equivariant line bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, k-theory

Let $L \to X$ be a $G$ equivariant line bundle over a projective variety $X$.

Then one has a $G$ action on the space of sections: a section $s: X \to L$ is sent to $g s (g x)$.

> I don't understand how one can get an action of $G$ on $H^i(X,L)$
>   except for a few special cases.  How can one get the action?

There are a few special cases I know where I can get an action by serre duality.  For instance if $G$ is $SL_2$, $X=G/B=\mathbb{P^1}$, $L$ is any line bundle, say $\mathcal O(d)$ for some $d$ then we know that from the cech resolution, that $H^1(\mathcal O(-d))=\mathbb{C}^{d-1}$ for $d \geq 2$ and zero otherwize and the $G-$module structure comes using that $H^1(\mathcal (O(-d)))=H^0(\mathcal O(d) \otimes K_x)^*=H^0(\mathcal O(d-2))^*=Sym^{d-2}(\mathbb{C}^{2})$ which is an irreducible representation of highest weight $(d-2) \epsilon_1$.

But it would be nice if I could see how to get an action on the higher cohomology groups and conclude using something else that the action is the same as what you get using Serre duality.

Comment: Let the projection map be $p: G \times X \to X$.  I would be happy with an answer that shows why $H^*(G \times X, p^*(L))=C[G] \otimes H^*(X, L)$

Comment: If we had this isomorphism then we would have the same action we have on the space of sections.

Comment: Does working over $\mathbb{C}$ and using the Dolbeault isomorphism not work?

Comment: Are you suggesting using a global definition of the chain groups as in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103705/global-definition-of-the-dolbeault-complex-of-a-vector-bundle?  Then one has a $G$-action on each of the chain groups and hence cohomology.

Comment: I just meant using the induced action on differential forms and the Dolbeault resolution to get a description of the action. That could be good enough for what you want.

Comment: Just because one has a $G$ equivariant structure on a line bundle, it doesn't mean that there is a $G$ equivariant structure on $\Omega^{p,q}$ compatible with the action on the base of the line bundle.  For example $\mathcal O(n) \to \mathbb{P}^n$ is a $PGL(n+1,\mathbb{C})$ equivariant line bundle, but the cotangent bundle of $\mathbb{P^n}$ is not a $PGL(n+1,\mathbb{C})$ equivariant line bundle.